# Issue in converting code to angular typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-cli

i have an application which tokenize the input string depending upon the delimeter entered. My current code works well. But now i am trying to convert my code to angular 2 which makes use of typescript. I don't know what the issue in typescript and how to place my filter and modules in .ts files. I have used angular cli to develop project repository.

Here's my current code for angular :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('HelloController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Angular is Awesome";
    //$scope.delimeter="#";
})


.filter('tokenize', function () {
return function (value, optionalArg) {
    if (angular.isString(value)) {
        var abc=[];
        abc=value.split('');
        value=abc.join(optionalArg);
        return value;
    } else {
        return value;
  }
 }
});
```

Here's my html file:

```
    <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
    <label>Input</label><input ng-model='greeting'><br><br>
    <label>Delimeter</label><input ng-model='arg1'><br>
    <p>{{greeting | tokenize}}(default)</p>
    <p>{{greeting | tokenize:arg1}}(with Option)</p>
   </div>
```

the problem is now i am trying to code using typescript. i have issues in angular cli files. Below is my p.component.ts code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-part2',
   templateUrl: './part2.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./part2.component.css']
   })
  export class Part2Component implements OnInit {
   greeting: string;
   constructor() {
   this.greeting="Angular is awesome";
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
 }
```

and my html code is

```
       <input type="text" {{ng-model}}='greeting'><br><br>
       <input type="text" {{ng-model}}='arg1'><br>
       <p>{{greeting | tokenize}}(default)</p>
       <p>{{greeting | tokenize:arg1}}(with Option)</p>
```

I also have tokenize.ts file where i need to put the filter created by me.
But the problem is when i compile code using angular cli it gives no result. So kindly help me in doing so. The output of program without tokenize is given below by image.

[image]

Comment: can you reproduce this in stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubxtfj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: https://angular-ubxtfj.stackblitz.io

Comment: That's not how you use ngModel. You need to actually learn how to use Angular. https://angular.io/guide/forms